# how to use another public class as a field in a class?

Tags: c#

```
public class Sprite {
    private Point p;
    private uint Horiz;
    private uint Vert;
    private uint Health;
    private uint Shield;

    /* Default constructor
     * set all values to 0
     */
    public Sprite()
    {
        p =  new Point();
        Horiz = 0;
        Vert = 0;
        Health = 0;
        Shield = 0;
    }
```

New to c#. These are my member fields for class Sprite. I have another class Point, I am trying to use point as one of my member fields and initialize it in the constructor but I am getting an error: "The type or namespace name `Point' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?". Is this type of practice possible or recommended? Should I just have my point class as a "nested" class? Thanks!

Comment: Where is `Point` ?

Comment: Point has to be in another file, this is for school

Comment: Are both files in the same .csproj? If so, are both classes in the same namespace? If they aren't, is there an appropriate `using` directive at the top of `Sprite`'s file?

Comment: Ahh, I see, thanks Etinnene!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, you need to **add a namespace reference** from your Point class.

Put the cursor in this Point declaration and press **Ctrl . (Control dot)**.

Or manually, above of the declaration of the class you have the **namespace**, like this:

```
namespace MyApp.Model 
{
   public class MyClass
   {
      //property and behaviors
   }
}
```

For use MyClass in other class that have a **different namespace**, you need to add a reference, above the namespace

```
using Myapp.Model // because this line you can use MyClass below

namespace Myapp.Controllers
{
   public class MyController
   {
      private MyClass ...
   }
}
```